# Javascript to replace all external links

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

What I am trying to achieve is replacing all external links when page is loaded.

As an example, the original url:

```
http://microsoft.com/faq become newurl
```

should be changed to:

```
http://redirect.com/?url=http://microsoft.com/faq
```

I tried different solutions I found with Google, but nothing seems to work for me.

I think I found a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/eK7XW/

Comment: This question seems to have nefarious intentions / spammer written all over it.

Comment: If you gave us your markup it would be a whole lot easier to help you.

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` and a `for` loop to iterate the found elements. Inside the loop, check that the `href`'s domain isn't your domain. If so, replace the `href` property with `http://redirect.com/?url=` + the original `href`

Comment: Brad M, get a life mate. You think I own ms.com or redirect.com? :D

Comment: No Ivan, I doubt anyone thinks you own either of those domains, but examples can be changed. Personally, I don't care what you do with the information. Nobody is hacking one of my sites with such a simple script.

Comment: iGanja, sorry... who r u?

Comment: Just the guy putting your simple question into perspective. Sorry, if I don't find it all that "nefarious". Carry On!

Comment: iGanja Thank you! Appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to check internal domain:

```
function isExternal(link, domain) {
    var re = /http(s?):\/\/([\w]+\.){1}([\w]+\.?)+/;
    return re.exec(link)[0] === domain;
}

var SITE = "http://redirect.com/?url=";
var INTERNAL_DOMAIN = "http://www.yourdomain.com";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    if (isExternal(links[i].href), INTERNAL_DOMAIN) {
        links[i].href = SITE + links[i].href;
    }
}
```

If you need to check for subdomains or to not specify the internal domain, I believe the code is easy to adapt.

Comment: This doesn't check whether the link is external/internal

Comment: I will use this peace of code as well but for something else. Thanks for you attention!

Comment: In response to Ian, just add an indexOf check against "http://" or a dictionary of internal domains, and this script will work just fine.

Comment: @iGanja No, not really. `http://` isn't a domain and is unhelpful with this. And the `href` property would have to be parsed and checked correctly/accurately for this to be a complete solution. All this is showing is how to loop over `<a>` elements, which is important, but incomplete for the OP

Comment: Ian, if all of your "internal" links are relational, then a "parse" of the "href" property will reveal that all "external" links will carry the protocol. If your internal links are not coded as relational, then you will have to check each against a dictionary of internal domains - yes, still requiring parsing.

Comment: @iGanja Very true. In the perfect world where all internal links are relational. Who said they were?

Comment: I didn't, which is why I offered both solutions. Sorry if I expect people on SO to have SOME knowledge. If I were to give a complete solution, I'd write an Answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @iGanja Good point. I'm just trying to rationalize why this specific answer is/was incomplete